# Contar linhas que possuem o mesmo valor em 2 colunas diferentes?

Tags: mysql, sql

## Tabela

```
ID    jogada    pontos
1       1          3
1       1          1
2       5          1 
2       5          1
2       5          3
2       5          3
```

Eu queria criar uma consulta que CONTA as linhas de jogada e SOMA o total de pontos, mas que indique a soma repetindo o "ID" assim:

Retorno que espero:

```
ID    contar_jogada    somar_pontos
1       2                   4
2       4                   8
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a função [SUM](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_sum.asp) para somar os pontos, [COUNT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_msaccess_count.asp) para contar as jogadas e Group By para agrupar pelo ID.

## Query

```
SELECT id AS ID, 
Count(jogada) AS TotalJogada, 
Sum(pontos)   AS Pontos 
FROM   tablename 
GROUP  BY id
```